# Expand/Collapse indexed tableView cells with searchController

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, tableview, expand

I have a tableView with different subcategories ("Algrebra","Biology","Chemistry") who are indexed and searchable via the searchController. I want to put these subcategories inside multiple categories ("Urgent","Important","Not Important") and expand/collapse them on click. I also want to have the categories indexed (instead of the subcategories) but keep the subcategories searchable via the searchController.

[image]

I don't know how to implement it properly with my code.

Here's my code:

**CategoryController**

```
class CategoryController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    private var searchController = UISearchController()

let categories = ["Urgent", "Important", "Not Important"] 

let subcategories = [                                                                  
        Add(category: "Algrebra", categoryImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Algebra.png")),
        Add(category: "Biology", categoryImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Biology.png")),
        Add(category: "Chemistry", categoryImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Chemistry.png")),
    ]
    private var sectionTitles = [String]()
    private var filteredSectionTitles = [String]()
    private var sortedCategory = [(key: String, value: [Add])]()
    private var filteredCategory = [(key: String, value: [Add])]()

  private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return table }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//TABLEVIEW
        tableView.rowHeight = 50
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.sectionIndexColor = .black
        tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .lightGray
        tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = .gray
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
//SEARCHCONTROLLER
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for your category"
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        self.navigationItem.title = "Tasks"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .label
        
        
        let groupedList = Dictionary(grouping: self.subcategories, by: { String($0.category.prefix(1)) })
        self.sortedCategory = groupedList.sorted{$0.key < $1.key}
        
        for tuple in self.sortedCategory {
            self.sectionTitles.append(tuple.key)
        }
    }
//VIEWDIDLAYOUT
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }
/// TABLEVIEW
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if self.searchController.isActive && !self.filteredSectionTitles.isEmpty {
            return self.filteredSectionTitles[section]
        } else {
            return self.sectionTitles[section]
        }
    }
    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        if self.searchController.isActive && !self.filteredSectionTitles.isEmpty {
            return self.filteredSectionTitles
        } else {
            return self.sectionTitles
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if self.searchController.isActive && !self.filteredSectionTitles.isEmpty {
            return self.filteredSectionTitles.count
        } else {
            return self.sectionTitles.count
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.searchController.isActive && !self.filteredCategory.isEmpty {
            return self.filteredCategory[section].value.count
        } else {
            return self.sortedCategory[section].value.count
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        if self.searchController.isActive && !self.filteredCategory.isEmpty {
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredCategory[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].category
            cell.imageView?.image = self.filteredCategory[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].categoryImg
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.sortedCategory[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].category
            cell.imageView?.image = self.sortedCategory[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].categoryImg
            
        }
        return cell
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
        Add.details.category = (currentCell.textLabel?.text)!
        let secondVC = DateController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        print(Add.details.category)

    }
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    
    guard let text = self.searchController.searchBar.text else {
        return
    }
    let filteredCategory = self.sortedCategory.flatMap { $0.value.filter { $0.category.contains(text) } }
    let groupedCategory = Dictionary(grouping: filteredCategory, by: { String($0.category.prefix(1)) } )
    self.filteredCategory = []
    self.filteredCategory = groupedCategory.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key }
    
    self.filteredSectionTitles = []
    for tuple in self.filteredCategory {
        self.filteredSectionTitles.append(tuple.key)
    }
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

**CategoryCell**

```
class CategoryCell: UITableViewCell {
    var cellImageView = UIImageView()
    var cellLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
            
            cellImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            cellImageView.tintColor = .systemPink
            contentView.addSubview(cellImageView)
            
            cellLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cellLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
            contentView.addSubview(cellLabel)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                cellImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
                cellImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
                cellImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
                cellImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
                
                cellLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
                cellLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
                
            ])
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

     }
    
        
}
```

**Add(DataStruct)**

```
struct Add {
    static var details: Add = Add()
    var category: String = ""
    
    func getDict() -> [String: Any] {
              let dict = ["category": self.category,
                         
                ] as [String : Any]
               return dict
         }

}
```

Comment: Forget about your code for a moment, and try to write a better description of your goal -- because it's not quite clear. Does "Chemistry" have sub-items such as   "Analytical / Biological / Inorganic / Organic / Physical", and you want to expand/collapse "Chemistry" as well as making its sub-items searchable? Or, are "Algrebra", "Biology", "Chemistry" *items* that you want searchable and displayed sorted within expandable "Urgent","Important","Not Important" sections?

Comment: Sorry for the messy explanation. So no, Chemistry does not have any sub-items and yes that's exactly what i want, i want to make Algebra/Biology/Chemistry searchable and within Urgent/Important/NotImportant sections. (And make Urgent/Important/NotImportant indexable instead of Algebra/Biology/Chemistry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple tips that should help...

First, let's change some naming.

You're using your "Categories" of "Urgent","Important","Not Important" as *Sections* ... and your "subcategories" would be more accurately described as "Categories".

We can also think of the Sections as perhaps *Category Status*

So, we'll create an `enum` like this:

```
enum CategoryStatus: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case urgent
    case important
    case notimportant
    
    var description : String {
        switch self {
        case .urgent: return "Urgent"
        case .important: return "Important"
        case .notimportant: return "Not Important"
        }
    }
    
    var star : UIImage {
        switch self {
        case .urgent: return UIImage(named: "star") ?? UIImage()
        case .important: return UIImage(named: "halfstar") ?? UIImage()
        case .notimportant: return UIImage(named: "emptystar") ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
}
```

And we'll add a "status" property to the Category struct:

```
struct MyCategory {
    var name: String = ""
    var categoryImg: UIImage = UIImage()
    var status: CategoryStatus = .important
}
```

Now, we can work through the process using "plain language":

- start by sorting the entire category list by name
- when we type a search string, we can filter that list by "name contains search"
- when can then group that list by status

So if we start with:

```
Biology : .important
Chemistry : .urgent
Algebra : .urgent
```

we can sort on name and get

```
Algebra : .urgent
Biology : .important
Chemistry : .urgent
```

then group by status

```
.urgent
    Algebra
    Chemistry
.important
    Biology
```

If we have typed "b" in the search field, we start with our sorted ALL list, and filter it:

```
Algebra : .urgent
Biology : .important
```

then group by status

```
.urgent
    Algebra
.important
    Biology
```

Another tip: instead of using a "full list" and a "filtered list", along with a bunch of

```
if self.searchController.isActive && !self.filteredSectionTitles.isEmpty {
```

blocks, use a single sorted, filtered and grouped list.

That list will then be set to either A) the FULL list (if there is no search text entered) or B) the Filtered list

Here is a complete example you can try out. I used a bunch of random topics as Categories, and used numbers in circles for each category image, and I used pngs of star, halfstar and emptystar.

Please note this is ***Example Code Only!***. It is not meant to be, and should not be considered to be, "Production Ready":

```
enum CategoryStatus: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case urgent
    case important
    case notimportant
    
    var description : String {
        switch self {
        case .urgent: return "Urgent"
        case .important: return "Important"
        case .notimportant: return "Not Important"
        }
    }
    
    var star : UIImage {
        switch self {
        case .urgent: return UIImage(named: "star") ?? UIImage()
        case .important: return UIImage(named: "halfstar") ?? UIImage()
        case .notimportant: return UIImage(named: "emptystar") ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
}

struct MyCategory {
    var name: String = ""
    var categoryImg: UIImage = UIImage()
    var status: CategoryStatus = .important
}

class CategoryController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    private var searchController = UISearchController()
    
    // array of ALL Categories, sorted by name
    private var sortedCategories: [MyCategory] = []
    
    // this will be either ALL items, or the filtered items
    //  grouped by Status
    private var sortedByStatus = [(key: CategoryStatus, value: [MyCategory])]()
    
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    
    private let noMatchesLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.text = "NO Matches"
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var items: [MyCategory] = []
        
        // this will be our list of MyCategory objects (they'll be sorted later)
        let itemNames: [String] = [
            "Algebra",
            "Chemistry",
            "Biology",
            "Computer Sciences",
            "Physics",
            "Earth Sciences",
            "Geology",
            "Political Science",
            "Psychology",
            "Nursing",
            "Economics",
            "Agriculture",
            "Communications",
            "Engineering",
            "Foreign Lanuages",
            "English Language",
            "Literature",
            "Libary Sciences",
            "Social Sciences",
            "Visual Arts",
        ]
        
        // create our array of MyCategory
        //  setting every 3rd one to .urgent, .important or .notimportant
        for (str, i) in zip(itemNames, 0...30) {
            let status: CategoryStatus = CategoryStatus.init(rawValue: i % 3) ?? .important
            var img: UIImage = UIImage()
            if let thisImg = UIImage(named: str) {
                img = thisImg
            } else {
                if let thisImg = UIImage(systemName: "\(i).circle") {
                    img = thisImg
                }
            }
            items.append(MyCategory(name: str, categoryImg: img, status: status))
        }
        
        // sort the full list of categories by name
        self.sortedCategories = items.sorted{$0.name < $1.name}
        
        //TABLEVIEW
        tableView.rowHeight = 50
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.sectionIndexColor = .black
        tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .lightGray
        tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = .gray
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CategoryCell.reuseIdentifier)
        tableView.register(MySectionHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: MySectionHeaderView.reuseIdentifier)
        
        //SEARCHCONTROLLER
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for your category"
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        self.navigationItem.title = "Tasks"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .label
        
        // add the no-matches view
        noMatchesLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(noMatchesLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
            noMatchesLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7),
            noMatchesLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            noMatchesLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            noMatchesLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.frameLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            
        ])
        
        noMatchesLabel.isHidden = true
        
        // call updateSearchResults to build the initial non-filtered data
        updateSearchResults(for: searchController)
        
    }
    
    /// TABLEVIEW
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let v = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: MySectionHeaderView.reuseIdentifier) as! MySectionHeaderView
        v.imageView.image = self.sortedByStatus[section].key.star
        v.label.text = self.sortedByStatus[section].key.description
        return v
    }
    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        // first char of each section title
        return (sortedByStatus.map { $0.key.description }).compactMap { String($0.prefix(1)) }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.sortedByStatus.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.sortedByStatus[section].value.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CategoryCell.reuseIdentifier, for:indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        
        cell.cellLabel.text = self.sortedByStatus[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].name
        cell.cellImageView.image = self.sortedByStatus[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].categoryImg
        
        return cell
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        // get Category object from data
        let thisCategory: MyCategory = self.sortedByStatus[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row]
        print("selected:", thisCategory.name, "status:", thisCategory.status)
        
    }
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        var filteredList: [MyCategory] = []
        
        if let text = self.searchController.searchBar.text, !text.isEmpty {
            
            // we have text to search for, so filter the list
            filteredList = self.sortedCategories.filter { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(text) }
            
        } else {
            
            // no text to search for, so use the full list
            filteredList = self.sortedCategories
            
        }
        
        // filteredList is now either ALL Categories (no search text entered), or
        //  ALL Categories filtered by search text
        
        // create a dictionary of items grouped by status
        let groupedList = Dictionary(grouping: filteredList, by: { $0.status })
        
        // order the grouped list by status
        self.sortedByStatus = groupedList.sorted{$0.key.rawValue < $1.key.rawValue}
        
        // show noMatchesLabel if we have NO matching Categories
        noMatchesLabel.isHidden = self.sortedByStatus.count != 0
        
        // reload the table
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
}

// simple cell with image view and label
class CategoryCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)
    
    var cellImageView = UIImageView()
    var cellLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        cellImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cellImageView.tintColor = .systemPink
        contentView.addSubview(cellImageView)
        
        cellLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        contentView.addSubview(cellLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            cellImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            cellImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            cellImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            cellImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
            
            cellLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            cellLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
}

// simple reusable section header with image view and label
class MySectionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)
    
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
        
        [imageView, label].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
}
```

Here's how it looks when launched:

[image]

then, as we type "t" "e" "ra":

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit**

The `for (str, i) in zip(itemNames, 0...30) {` block in the example code was just an easy way to generate some example items.

To use this in your code, you would likely do something like this:

```
let items = [
    MyCategory(name: "Algebra", categoryImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Algebra.png"), status: .urgent),                                                                 
    MyCategory(name: "Biology", categoryImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Biology.png"), status: .important),                                                                 
    MyCategory(name: "Chemistry", categoryImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Chemistry.png"), status: .notimportant),
    // and so on                                                                 
]
```

Comment: Damn thank you Don, why i didn't thought of using Enum/switch case like this, it's way cleaner and i can even add the category status to my data struct in case i want to use it later ^^ I implemented your code into mine and it's almost perfect.  The only thing is i don't know how to put the categories (algebra ect...) into the status header in a non-random way and with a selected image next to it instead of the number and the circle

Comment: It's this part of the code i can't comprehend/change ```for (str, i) in zip(itemNames, 0...30) { let status: CategoryStatus = CategoryStatus.init(rawValue: i % 3) ?? .important
var img: UIImage = UIImage()
            if let thisImg = UIImage(named: str) {
                img = thisImg
            } else {
                if let thisImg = UIImage(systemName: "\(i).circle") {
                    img = thisImg }}
            items.append(MyCategory(name: str, categoryImg: img, status: status))
        }```

Comment: @dohoudjann - see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Perfect, you're a beast ! Thank you again for the answer and the clear explanation...